# Finding about Eclipse dependency (e.g. for red5)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, red5

According to the Red5 plugin for eclipse,

> You must use the **Java EE distribution** of Eclipse. The **standard** Java distribution will not work.

But what part exacty of the Java EE distribution is needed. This way I can bring my current distribution of Eclipse to the level needed for Red5 without having to install an entirely new distribution just for Red5.

If you don't have an answer, but can point me to a way I can find it out for myself somehow what that dependency could be, that would be good enough too.

Answer (score 1):

The installation processed described [in this page](http://www.red5.org/wiki/Red5Plugin) is through an old pre-**[P2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Equinox_p2)** area with eclipse3.3

[image]
<sub>(source: [red5.org](http://www.red5.org/raw-attachment/wiki/Red5Plugin/Picture%206.png))</sub>

You could try the same update site, with an [basic eclipse3.5.1](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/): the [P2 provisioning mechanism](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_User_Interface) should list for you all the missing components.

You can then compare the missing packages with the [different eclipse distros](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) and see for yourself exactly what part if the J2EE distro you actually need for the Red5 eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Every eclipse plugin has an (unique) identifier and a list with identifier it depends upon. If you unzip the jar file you will find a directory "META-INF" with a textfile "MANIFEST.MF". There will be an entry "Require-Bundle:" with a list of bundles (e.g. org.junit4;bundle-version="4.5.0"). This list tells you what you have to install for the plugin to work.

The id of the plugin is the entry "Bundle-SymbolicName:". With the ids on hand you should be able to determine what plugins exactly you have to install.

Answer (score 0):

You mainly need the JST and WST plugins available from Eclipse themselves.